# Facebook API & Ajax POST request

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, api

I have a Facebook connect/disconnect link. When user clicks on "Facebook connect" link (on **index.php**), it checks the user state (Is he connected to Facebook or not?) then if he's not connected, my script sends an Ajax $.post request to **connect.php** in order to retrieve infos from database (for instance : Is the user registered in our database?). After that, it sends back a response to index.php : if there is no error, the page is refreshed. In this case, if everything is ok, after the page is refreshed by the script (**window.location.reload();**), we should see the Facebook user ID (UID).

The problem is the UID is still empty after the page is reloaded through the ajax callback. But, if I refresh the page manually one more time, I can now see the UID.

I test many ways to understand where the problem comes from, and I found there is a problem with this Facebook request : **$me = $facebook->api('/me');**

Anyway, I can't do without **$me = $facebook->api('/me');** so if you want to test my script and find the problem, here is what you need ! (don't forget the last Facebook SDK) ;-)

Any help would be very apreciated ! Thanks !

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Facebook Connect</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<?php

/* FACEBOOK APP CONFIGURATION */
$appId = 'YOU_APP_ID';
$appSecret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

define("APPID",$appId);
define("APPSECRET",$appSecret);

/* API CALL */
if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException'))
{
  require_once('inc/facebook.php' );
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId' => APPID,
   'secret' => APPSECRET,
));

$fb_user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fb_user) {
    try
    {
       $me = $facebook->api('/me');
       $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    }
      catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
       //echo error_log($e);
       $fb_user = null;
    }
}
?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<?=APPID?>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId   : '<?=APPID?>',
            oauth   : true,
            status  : true,
            cookie  : true,
            xfbml   : true
        });
    };

    function fb_connect() {
        alert('FB.getLoginStatus');
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                //
                window.location.reload();
                //
            } else {
                alert('FB.login');
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                        $.post('connect.php', function(data) {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (obj['error']==0) {
                            alert(obj['message']);
                            window.location.reload();
                        } else {
                            alert(obj['message']);
                        }
                    });
                    //

                }, {
                    scope: 'email, publish_stream, user_birthday'
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function fb_logout() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            window.location.reload();
        }); 
    }

    (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js';
      e.async = true;
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<p>UID : <?=$fb_user?></p>
<?php if ($fb_user) { ?>
<a href="#" onclick="fb_logout();">Disconnect</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="#" onclick="fb_connect();">Facebook connect</a>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
/* FACEBOOK APP CONFIGURATION */
$appId = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$appSecret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

define("APPID",$appId);
define("APPSECRET",$appSecret);

/* API CALL */
if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException'))
{
  require_once('inc/facebook.php' );
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId' => APPID,
   'secret' => APPSECRET,
));

$fb_user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fb_user) {
    try
    {
       $me = $facebook->api('/me');
       $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    }
      catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
       //echo error_log($e);
       $fb_user = null;
    }
}

/* CALLBACK */
$result = array();

if ($fb_user) {
    $result['error'] = 0;
    $result['message'] = $me['first_name'];;
} else {
    $result['error'] = 1;
    $result['message'] = 'error';
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked for error messages/exceptions thrown from your PHP script? Btw., I don’t see you POSTing any data to your `connect.php`, and all this file does is requesting user data from Facebook and sending it back to the client as JSON – only to then reload the page, so that the whole _requesting user data from Facebook_ part is done _again_ – what’s the logic behind that please?

Comment: You're right, I don't POST anything here, but I just ask Facebook to connect user through ajax and send back the JSON data (in fact I've shortened the script but it checks info in database in connect.php in real). But once I go back and dynamically refresh the index.php page, normally I should be Facebook authenticated and I should see my Facebook infos. But it fails. Only a manual page refresh lets me see my FB infos. So I don't understand...

Comment: Well have you tried it without this still pretty superfluous sounding AJAX step – after login, just reload the index.php …?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not superfluous, I really need it to check things in database. In fact, if the user is not registered in database, the user is redirected to another page instead reloading the index page with the new SESSION vars. Anyway, I need to understand why I can't retrieve my FB infos by reloading dynamically instead manually. This is the real problem. You see what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, but it's not superfluous, I really need it to check things in database. In fact, if the user is not registered in database, the user is redirected to another page instead reloading the index page

So, as I suspected, no real need for the AJAX call.

You could just as well reload your `index.php`, do your database checks there, and then either put out content for a successfully logged in user, or redirect them from there using a *Location* header.

> Anyway, I need to understand why I can't retrieve my FB infos by reloading dynamically instead manually. This is the real problem.

Well then you should investigate your *real* problem: Debug the exception you might be getting, or check what differences there are in the login flow using that extra AJAX step or avoiding it (like what cookies get set when, do they get send back with the next request, etc.)